# Multiple OR comparisons for one array position

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

Sorry, I couldnt word the subject particularly well.
Quite simply I have an IF statement where I am comparing if three conditions are met;

```
if(buffer[i] == "N" && (buffer[i+1] == "1"||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5") && buffer[i+2] == " ")
```

I know that N is always going to be present, the character after that needs to then be a number from 1 to 5, after that is whitespace. This does compile but does not produce any result, at a safe guess I would say it is my horrendous code above.

I should add, this is within a while loop that advances through the buffer until whitespace ends.

Have I over-complicated a simple problem or am I on the right tracks but with crappy syntax?

Thanks for any suggestions or hints.

Comment: turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: They are on but I need to work on my actioning of them. But yes sorry. Thats the second time I have been pointed towards looking at my warnings! I'll try and up the warning level to avoid letting more errors slip through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below two expressions are equivalent. You are `||`ing the wrong stuff.

- `(buffer[i+1] == "1"||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5")`
- `(((((buffer[i+1] == "1")||"2")||"3")||"4")||"5")`

What you are trying to achieve is.

- `(buffer[i+1] >= '1' && buffer[i+1] <= '5')`

Also, I believe that your code won't compile because single string elements are of `char` type. Their literals are represented with `'1'`, `'2'`, `'N'` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I always over-complicate something which can be done with much more finesse.

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `||` so the expression is actually equivalent to `(buffer[i+1] == "1")||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5"`

Answer (score 2):

You can't ask

buffer[i+1] == "1"||"2"

you have to ask

buffer[i+1] == "1" || buffer[i+1] == "2"

But if these are C strings, then you can't use == at all -- you have to use the strcmp() function from the standard library, which returns 0 when two strings are equal:

strcmp(buffer[i+1], "1") == 0 || strcmp(buffer[i+1], "2") == 0

Comment: Hi, while it is a string within an array, I can treat each position within the array as a char can't I?

Comment: You can, that's what string is.

Comment: Actually, you can ask `buffer[i+1] == "1"||"2"` but it evaluates as `(buffer[i+1] == "1")||"2"` and `"2"` is a constant pointer which is guaranteed to evaluate to true (i.e. it is non zero) so the whole expression is true.  Anyway, +1 for the right answer.

Comment: Yes you can -- the double-quotes were throwing me. See MByD's answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I have a fairly good understanding of strings and chars so your comment did throw me! It wouldn't be the first time a compiler had let me do things I shouldn't have been doing :)

Answer (score 1):

The 1st comparison should be `buffer[i] == 'N'` , not `buffer[i] == "N"` because you want to compare chars, and "N" is a pointer to char, not a char.

The 2nd comparison should be `buffer[i+1] >= '1' && buffer[i+1] <='5'` for the same reason.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I'm accepting the above as answer as it directly answered my question first but up-vote for pointing out the mistake! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Or doesn't work that way, and neither do string comparisons in C. First of all, you probably wanted to compare to `char`s.

Secondly, `a == b||c||d||e` is equivalent to `a == (b||c||d||e)` which will probably end up being 1.

What you meant to say was (naively) `(buffer[i+1] == '1') || (buffer[i+1] == '2') || (buffer[i+1] == '3') ...`

An easier way to say it, since you're using ASCII characters, is:

```
(buffer[i+1] >= '1') && (buffer[i+1] <= '5')
```

Don't forget to replace `"N"` and `" "` with `'N'` and `' '`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use sscanf:

```
char digit[2];

if (1==sscanf(buffer+i, "N%[12345][ ]", &digit))
    // It matched. `digit` holds the digit we found in string form.
```